# How to increase CodedInputStream.setSizeLimit()

Tags: java, hive, inputstream, reader, orc

I am Trying to read an ORC file in Java using

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Reader createReader = OrcFile.createReader( new Path("/a"), OrcFile.readerOptions(conf));
```

I am getting the following Error

> com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message
>   was too large.  May be malicious.  Use CodedInputStream.setSizeLimit()
>   to increase the size limit.

This issue has been resolved here for another program. https://code.google.com/p/protobufeditor/issues/detail?id=2

But I am not sure of howthey did it.
Could you Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a lot of stuff here 
Maybe this can help you [OrcNewInputFormat Test](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/ql/src/test/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/orc/TestNewInputOutputFormat.java)